How do I use additional assigned coordinate in the xarray dataset for hover tooltips in hvplot?
I am encountering an issue when trying to include custom coordinates (xind and yind ) in tooltips while using hvplot.image() .
Here is a minimal reproducible example of my code:
import hvplot.xarray

sample_data = np.random.rand(500, 128)
y_coord = np.linspace(0, 15, 500)
x_coord = np.linspace(0, 1, 128)

data = xr.DataArray(data=sample_data.T, coords=[("y", x_coord), ("x", y_coord)])

xindex = np.arange(len(x_coord))
yindex = np.arange(len(y_coord))
data = data.assign_coords(xind=("x", yindex))
data = data.assign_coords(yind=("y", xindex))

plot = data.hvplot.image(
z="value",
x="x",
y="y",
cmap="gray",
width=1200,
height=300,
hover=True,
xlabel="x (mm)",
ylabel="y (m)",
framewise=True,
rasterize=True,
)


When attempting to include xind and yind coordinates in tooltips using hover_cols=["xind","yind"] , I encounter the following error:
ValueError: 'y' is not in list
  

Is there any way that would allow me to use xind and yind in my tooltips?

To include custom coordinates (xind and yind) in tooltips while using hvplot.image(), you can create a custom hover tooltip by defining a HoverTool with the desired formatting. Here’s how you can change your code to achieve this:
import hvplot.xarray
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

sample_data = np.random.rand(500, 128)
y_coord = np.linspace(0, 15, 500)
x_coord = np.linspace(0, 1, 128)

data = xr.DataArray(data=sample_data.T, coords=[("y", x_coord), ("x", y_coord)])

xindex = np.arange(len(x_coord))
yindex = np.arange(len(y_coord))
data = data.assign_coords(xind=("x", yindex))
data = data.assign_coords(yind=("y", xindex))

# Create a custom hover tooltip
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[("xind", "@xind"), ("yind", "@yind")])

plot = data.hvplot.image(
    z="value",
    x="x",
    y="y",
    cmap="gray",
    width=1200,
    height=300,
    framewise=True,
    rasterize=True,
    tools=[hover],  # Add the custom hover tool
)

plot.opts(xlabel="x (mm)", ylabel="y (m)")

In this modified code, we create a custom HoverTool with tooltips for xind and yind.
The tools argument in hvplot.image() is set to include the custom hover tool.
Now your plot should display tooltips with the custom coordinates.

I am sorry but this seems like a ChatGPT answer. Doesn't work. xind and yind show up as ??? on the plot.

What do you mean "This seems like a ChatGPT answer. Doesn't work"? It works perfectly fine.

No it doesn't work

I think you need set "xind" and "yind" as new indexes:
reindex = data.set_index( { "x": "xind", "y": "yind" } )

Here the difference:
Before reindex
After reindex
